Whatsapp link not opening chat with the specified contact
I am developing a angular chat in which i included a whatsapp link to open chat with the mentioned contact number. What I am facing is it navigates to the whatsapp chat properly but not opening chat with the provided contact. Note i am running my app at local host. Below is my code
.html
<fa-icon [icon]="['fab', 'whatsapp']" size="2x" class="me-2 whatsapp-icon" (click)="openWhatsApp()"></fa-icon>
.ts
openWhatsApp() { const phoneNumber = '92xxxxxxxxxx'; const message = encodeURIComponent('Hello, I would like to chat with you!'); const url = https://wa.me/${phoneNumber}?text=${message}; window.open(url, '_blank'); }
I have crosschecked the phone number its correct. I have also tried to create whatsapp link but it also not working. Can anybody suggest what is going wrong?
I tried to initialized chat but instead it only opening application with list of my old chats.

Constant formatting error:
Replace:
const url = https://wa.me/${phoneNumber}?text=${message};

With:
const url = `https://wa.me/${phoneNumber}?text=${message}`;

Hope this helps!

Rendering might be creating confusion here. Nasir should have delimited the code excerpt in the question with triple-back-ticks, but only used single ones. Because the url constant was also delimited by single back-ticks, it appeared as plain text. Similarly, your "With:" example shows a constant delimited by single back-ticks. If your constant value is as is intended, then Nasir already had the delimiters that you expected. To improve clarity, maybe Nasir should edit the question to delimit multi-line code excerpts with triple-back-ticks rather than single ones.
